# Omit output when calling seqdef

Tags: traminer

I wonder if it is possible to omit the output of the function `seqdef` of `TraMineR`. I do not see any `verbose` argument or similar.

Thank you!
Víctor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean suppressing messages. So just use `suppressMessages(seqdef(...))` as in the example below. Note that `suppressMessages` is a base R function and can be used with other functions such as `seqdist` or `seqrep`.

```
library(TraMineR)
data(biofam)
biofam.lab <- c("Parent", "Left", "Married", "Left+Marr",
                "Child", "Left+Child", "Left+Marr+Child", "Divorced")
biofam.short <- c("P","L","M","LM","C","LC","LMC","D")
biofam.seq <- suppressMessages(seqdef(biofam[,10:25], alphabet=0:7, 
                     states=biofam.short, labels=biofam.lab))
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. What if I also want to remove a warning message due to the attribute `cpal`? (my state space is too large for a color palette). Should I combine `suppressMessages` and `suppressWarnings`?